# date sort returning last item in list instead of latest date

Tags: arrays, date, google-apps-script

Issue: date sort not returning max.

Desired output: return max/latest date in an array.

I have the function below in google apps script.
I'm passing dates and trying to get the largest date.
It sorts but returns the last item on the list instead of the latest date. Any help?

(dcmDates is pulled from a sheet and formatted as date.)

```
  lastDate = dcmDates.sort(function(a, b) {

                        if(isNaN(a)) { return -1; }
                        if(new Date(a) > new Date(b)) { return 1; }
                        if(new Date(a) <= new Date(b)) { return -1; }
                        //return 0;
                      
                        })[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem and it doesn't properly sort the array using your conditions. I tried to modify your function a little bit and simplified it to make it simpler for you to adjust your script if needed:

```
  lastDate = dcmDates.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(b) - new Date(a);
  })[0];
```

To easily access the max date, what you need to do is reverse the dates to subtract. This way, the max date will always be placed at the first index.

<s>For possible NaN cells, I haven't included it here, but you can add the NaN check before the return. The code above assumes that there are just date values in the cells.</s>

**EDIT:**

If you want to exclude the non-date data from the comparison/sort, you need to filter your dcmDates first before sorting.

```
var dcmDates = values.filter(date => !(isNaN(new Date(date).getTime())));
```

This is pretty self explanatory, but you just want to include valid dates before sorting. This doesn't exactly do what you want like putting the NaN values at the bottom of the sort, but the output for this will be the same, getting the valid latest date.

Comment: Thanks. The NaN / non-date check is pretty critical. Could you advise on that? I'm having trouble understanding how to sort those to the bottom.
Also, if a and b are dates, why do I have to make them dates again.
And if a or b are not dates, won't this throw an error?

Comment: it seems to ignore the text/notnumber items just fine as-is. thanks. I guess I was just overcomplicating it...

Comment: Hi @JasonTorpy, can you try and give me some specific values that might not be considered as a date on that column? i'll try replicating those on my end and will get back to you with an updated answer. One type of all possible non-date values if possible so we will not encounter unexpected results.

Comment: These include whitespaces, special characters, non standard format dates, dates that have different formats, etc. It might not be as critical as the other samples but wouldn't hurt if we also do something to prevent unnecessary failures.

Comment: @JasonTorpy, i've edited the answer and that should excluded non-date data from the sort so you can only get the valid latest date possible.

Comment: actually If found it easier to drop the non-dates from the sort array. I understand what you mean about the variety of things 'not a date' could be. exclude first then sort seemed to make more sense. what you have is working for me now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the date in ascending order and getting the 0th item from the result. Also, check whether the dates are correctly formatted before sorting.  Console.log and verify the output.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I did check formatting. there should be two functions there, the first deprioritizing NaN to the bottom. not sure if that would capture a date as well. And my intention would be to sort descending dates (then text/NaN at the bottom). And grab the first item.

Can you recommend a tweak to fix that?